# sending too many parameters to cloud function, PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions with Cloud Firestore.

I want to add 500000 elements in my database. I'm trying to send a post request to the Cloud Function passing 10000 elements to add but the Cloud Function logs `PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters`.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a single request that's too large, make multiple requests.  The maximum payload for a request to a Cloud Functions HTTP request (or callable function request) is 10MB. Don't exceed that.